# Область видимости в объекте

Tags: javascript

```
var calculator = {
read : function(){
    var sumOne = prompt('enter one number', '');
    console.log(sumOne);
};
calculator.read();

console.log(calculator.read.sumOne);
```

Как вывести`sumOne` в консоль не в объекте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sumOne` - локальная переменная в функции, из вне к ней доступа не получить. Но её можно вернуть из функции:

```js
var calculator = {
  read: function() {
    var sumOne = prompt('enter one number', '');
    return sumOne;
  }
};

var number = calculator.read();
console.log(number);
```

Comment: Если нужно сделать так, как хочет автор, то нужно вернуть не просто `sumOne`, а объект с опцией `sumOne`. Т.е. `return {sumOne: sumOne}`. В итоге будет вызываться `calculator.read().sumOne`. Это в дополнение к вашему ответу